# Verdet Constant and optical pumping

Tags: quantum-mechanics, polarization, quantum-optics

While studying Faraday rotation (linear magneto-optic rotation) I came across a fact that Faraday rotation can be enhanced. [Verdet constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verdet_constant) which depends on the wavelength can be enhanced as change in refractive index with change in wavelength is maximum near resonant light. Now if the incident light frequency is resonant with the atomic transition frequency then light will get absorbed in the medium and we'll get very less light at the output for observation. It is my understanding that optical pumping is done to make medium transparent to the resonant light, as when majority of electrons will be trapped in dark state we'll get considerable light at the output to measure change in the plane of polarization.
Is my understanding accurate or is there anything that i have missed? Does optical pumping enhance faraday rotation in some other way also?

Answer (score -1):

Faraday rotation directly corresponds to extent of optical pumping which in turn depends on multiple factors including laser frequency, intensity, polarization..

Refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_pumping

Edited:

Verdet Constant is defined as optical rotation (OR) of the plane of polarization of light per unit magnetic field per unit length of the optical path. For a given magnetic field and optical path length, Verdet constant will directly correspond to OR. What happens to optical rotation with or without optical pumping.

**When the medium is optically pumped**, there are more atoms in one spatial orientation. So if a linearly polarized light now enters the medium, it divides into right circularly and left circularly component. Right circularly light becomes more refractive (How does refraction change: refractive index depends on the difference between the oscillation frequency of light and electrons) and left circularly become less absorptive and hence the net refractive index changes and hence the plane of light now rotates more for the same magnetic field and optical path length